# SiriKit: Custom Intents - localization problem

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, sirikit

I have the problem, that Siri always responses with the english version of my intents. I have create a demo project to seperate out the relevant code:

I have 3 targets in my project:

[image]

The `.intentsdefinition` file is located in the framework (`Base`) and the classes are generated also there, as it was suggested in the WWDC talk (2018 - 211)

This file is also translated into the german language:

[image]

But the problem is, that if I create a shortcut/intent via the app (`INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController`) the action name is already in english (should be Hallo not Hello), but as you can see, the whole ViewController is localized in german:

[image]

The strange thing is, if I select the action to see more info, the string inside this view controller is in german.

[image]

If I add this shortcut to Siri, the info texts are all in german, if I use the Shortcuts.app. If I ask Siri about the state, the response is in german, but the custom response of my shortcut is in english.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported the problem to Apple (feedback) and got an answer today. The bug should be fixed with iOS 14 beta 5.

I can confirm, that this is fixed with the latest iOS beta 7.